# Blocking direct script access to a file

Tags: php, security

At the moment I do it like this:

In one file, lets call it `file_one.php`, I have

```
define( 'ROOT', realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );

require_once( ROOTPATH . '/file_two.php' );
```

And in `file_two.php` I then have this at the top:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ROOT' ) )
    exit;
```

So the contents of `file_two.php` can only be accessed if `ROOT` is defined, which happens in `file_one.php`. If you try to access `file_two.php` directly it won't work, is it right? Are there any flaws in this method?

Comment: An even better idea is to put it outside of the webroot if possible

Comment: That's how CodeIgniter seems to do it, so should be mostly secure. Although I agree with post above that if this is an issue, simply move it out of the docroot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting John Conde's comment to an answer:

The best way to ensure a file can't be accessed in a browser is by putting it outside the webroot.

You should have a folder named `www` or `public_html` or similar, that contains your website's files. Well, in the folder containing that, you can put an `includes` folder and have your script-access-only files in there. This way, they are completely inaccessible from the web, but the scripts can still get to them.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as you say. If someone types directly in the browser /../../file_two.php it will just exit. When file is loaded independently, without include, the ROOT is not defined.

Remember that in PHP one file includes others and other and pretty much ends up with a single file at the end. So, if your direct access variable is not defined somewhere BEFORE the check, it will not allow access.